# When to use variable of Interface type rather than concrete type

Tags: c#

I have a class which derives from an Interface. Now the class has to implement all the methods in the Interfaces + it additionally defines 2 more methods.
Now my question is , what is the benefit/usecases of doing this:

```
IMyInterface varInt= new ConcreteImp();
```

over,

```
ConcreteImp varInt= new ConcreteImp();
```

I see this pattern used every where in code blocks, but not sure why this is used.

Comment: Read this: [Designing C# Software With Interfaces](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/designing-c-software-with-interfaces/)

Comment: to understand it visually, write a dot after `varInt` (after declaration) and Intellisense will show the difference between the two.

Answer (score 2):

Benefit in using interfaces is in decreasing dependency of parts on concrete implementation of a software component. In one line you posted, you won't be able to see a benefit. Benefit can be gained in consumers of that interface.

> Edit: You would be well to [read this article on abstractions](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2012/11/14/abstractions-patterns-and-interfaces.aspx).

For example, lets say that you have a method which accepts an interface like so `Rent(IMovie)`. Another person will be able to write implementation of `Rent()` method without knowing specifics of `IMovie` type which you will pass in when calling the method. You will then be able to create multiple different `IMovie` implementations which may have different method of billing, but `Rent()` method doesn't have to take care of that.

```
void Rent(IMovie movie)
{
    var price = movie.Price();
    movie.MarkReserved();
}

public interface IMovie { }

public class Oldie : IMovie
{
    private decimal _oldieRate = 0.8;

    public decimal Price()
    {
        return MainData.RentPrice * _oldieRate;
    }
    public decimal MarkReserved()
    {
        _oldiesDb.MarkReserved(this, true);
    }
}


public class Blockbuster : IMovie
{
    private decimal _blockbusterRate = 1.2;

    public decimal Price()
    {
        return MainData.RentPrice * _blockbusterRate ;
    }
    public decimal MarkReserved()
    {
        _regularDb.MarkReserved(this, true);
    }
}
```

This is example of why interfaces are useful, but is not very nice example of code design.

As a rule of thumb, you should write methods so that they require least input they need to work, and that their output provides as much information for others to use when they call it. For example, take a look at following signature:

```
public List<Entity> Filter(IEnumerable<Entity> baseCollection){ ... }
```

This method requests only `IEnumerable<Entity>` so it can take different collection types, like `List<Entity>`, `Entity[]` or custom types some tool returns. But you return `List<Entity>` so that right away you are not limiting caller to just enumerable elements. She can use Linq on return value right away for example.

There are more benefits, like in unit testing, where you can create mock objects and tell them how to behave during interaction with rest of the code. Although, you can do this with classes with virtual methods now.

Comment: All the above advantages can also be achieved if we use Abstract classes or classes with Virtual methods. And classes are more flexible than interfaces. So i don't see any reason to use Interfaces over Classes except when there's a need of multiple inheritance.

Comment: That except portion of your comment is very core of question your asking. As you know multiple inheritance does not exist in .NET, and if a class already inherits one you won't be able to add another abstraction to it. Also, example with `IEnumerable<T>` is a very concrete example you see in real world quite often. How would you map a collection in NHibernate with an abstract class instead of `IList<T>`? You must not impose on others implementation of your class unless necessary, and quite often you don't even need abstract class as you don't need shared code.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that you want, elsewhere in the code, to be able to assign a different implementation of `IMyInterface` to the `varInt` variable. Then that variable needs to be declared with type `IMyInterface`.

Alternatively, if you want to make it clear to any code readers that all you intend to do with `varInt` is use the interface defined by `IMyInterface`, then the type declaration makes that clear.

Answer (score 1):

When you need to enforce functionality in the derived class use interface.

and when you need to pass data from super class to subclass then you use concrete class. Its the basic oop idea behind interface and subclass.

Answer (score 1):

In your concrete example I would say it doesn't matter as much since you are using `new` and creates a concrete type. When you start using [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) it starts to be more useful.

A scenario where it is more useful looks like the following:

```
public SomeResultType DoSomething(ISomeType obj)
{
    //to something with obj
    // return someResultType
}
```

The above can be called using any type as long as it implements `ISomeType`. But in your example using the `new` keyword I would instead use `var`. You will still be able to treat it as type it implements since it inherit that type.

Answer (score 1):

assume that IMyInterface have "Draw" method, now all derived classes have to implement "Draw" method. if you have a class "Engine" with a method "Render(IMyInterface shape)", you have only to call the "Draw" method no matter what the shape is. and every shape Draw itself as he wants.
you can take a look at Design Patterns and you can see the magic of interfaces ;)